# How to set cursor position on a particular offset in ckeditor5

Tags: cursor, angular7, hashtag, ckeditor5

I am trying to set cursor position in ckeditor5 to a certain offset but not able to set.

I am using following code but getting underfined errors. We are usign ckedtior5 from build. and bydefult it has selection module in it but then also it says undefined for `editor.getSelection()` and `selection.setTo( range )`

`var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
var bm = range.createBookmark();`

`const range = writer.createRange( start, end );
selection.setTo( range );`

any idea how do it ?

Comment: Are you using CKEditor 4 or CKEditor 5? Because the API you mentioned is from CKEditor 4. In CKEditor 5 you can use the [`Writer` API](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html) for that purpose.

Comment: I am using CKeditor5. I need to get cursor to  original position  after setdata.

Comment: Does `setData()` change the content of the editor? What do you call it for anyway?

Comment: Yes it is changing but it changing cursor position as well

Comment: It resets it to the beginning of the content, doesn't it? How would you know that the position the cursor was at before `setData()` will still exist when the content changes? What to do if not?

I'm trying to show you that what you want to do does not make sense because you can't predict certain situations. What do you use `setData()` for?

Comment: I am creating hashtag by putting # in front of any word in editor content. Is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: Maybe you could use the [text transformations](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-transformation.html) feature to append them for you?